# What do these reference edge cases in function definitions mean in Rust?

Tags: rust

I just finished parsing through a bunch of Rust function definitions, and ran into a few which I don't understand what they mean. Can you explain what these mean?

What is this `&mut &'a`?

```
pub fn take<R>(self: &mut &'a [T], range: R) -> Option<&'a [T]> where R: OneSidedRange<usize>,
```

What is this: `&mut &'a mut`:

```
pub fn take_mut<R>(self: &mut &'a mut [T], range: R) -> Option<&'a mut [T]> where R: OneSidedRange<usize>,
```

What is `&dyn`?

```
fn cause(&self) -> Option<&dyn Error>
```

What about wrapping a bigger thing, `&(dyn Error + 'static)`:

```
fn source(&self) -> Option<&(dyn Error + 'static)>
```

And `impl`?

```
pub fn resize_with(&mut self, new_len: usize, generator: impl FnMut() -> T)
```

And `&mut (dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static)`:

```
pub fn get_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut (dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static)>
```

I parsed these out of the rustdocs for the std lib.

Comment: Do you know what `&mut` and `&'a` mean on their own?

Comment: Yes I know about mutable references and lifetimes, but mutable lifetimes? I don't know about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `&mut &'a [T]`

This is a mutable reference to an immutable slice of `T`, where the slice has lifetime `'a`.  In Rust, references can be reseated if they are declared `mut`, so this is *somewhat* akin to a double pointer in C or C++ (except, of course, that Rust references can't be null, and the inner "reference" here is actually a slice).  This means that the function can both read the slice of `T` and replace it with a new slice, provided the new slice meets the `'a` lifetime requirement.

> `&mut &'a mut [T]`

This is exactly the same as above, except the slice is mutable, so the `T` values in the slice can be mutated.

> `&dyn Error`

This represents a reference to a value implementing `Error`, with [dynamic dispatch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/dyn.html).  This allows the function to return a borrowed reference from anything that implements the `Error` trait.  The caller doesn't know the concrete type of the value returned, but it can use any member of the `Error` trait with the returned reference.

This enables the function to determine the actual type of thing to borrow from at runtime, and subsequent calls to the function could return references to values of different types, so long as they all implement `Error`.

> `&(dyn Error + 'static)`

This is the same thing but with a lifetime bound, namely that the value referred to by the returned reference cannot itself reference anything non-static.

> `&mut (dyn Error + Send + Sync + 'static)`

Skipping ahead to this one because it relates to the last two examples.  This is pretty much the same as the last example, except that the returned reference is mutable, and there are two new trait bounds (`Send` and `Sync`).  The referent must therefore implement all three traits given, and contain no non-static references.

> `impl FnMut() -> T`

For function arguments, this is a convenient way to describe a generic type without explicitly declaring it.  In this case, it means "any type that implements `FnMut() -> T`" (which is a closure type that accepts no arguments and returns `T`).

These signatures are effectively equivalent in Rust:

```
fn example(f: impl FnMut() -> String);
fn example<T>(f: T) where T: FnMut() -> String;
```

`impl` makes generic arguments easier to express in simple cases.

A place where `impl` is more useful is as a return value, which you'll commonly see with iterators, like:

```
fn example(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item=&String> { ... }
```

This is convenient when the exact concrete return type is not very useful, and it's *necessary* when returning an anonymous type, such as a closure, by value.  This is a way to tell the compiler "the return type must implement this trait, but you figure out what the real return type is."  Notably, static dispatch is still possible on the returned value since the compiler does know the actual concrete type.

It also means that the function must still return the *exact same type of value everywhere it returns.*  The return type isn't dynamic, it's inferred.

Comment: I still don't quite get the difference between `&mut &'a mut [T]` and the other one. Why the need for 2 & and 2 mut? Reading your description I can't tell the difference between the two.

Comment: @Lance The outer `mut` controls the mutability of the reference-to-slice. If the `mut` were not there, the outer reference could not be made to point to a different slice. The inner `mut` controls the mutability of the slice contents. If that `mut` were not there, the `T` elements in the slice could not be modified.

Comment: @Lance If you're familiar with C++, and we disregard the fact that Rust slices know their length and that Rust references can't be null, a Rust `&[T]` is like a C++ `T const *`. A `&mut [T]` is like `T *`. A `&mut &mut [T]` is like a `T **`. A `&mut &[T]` is like a `T const **`. A `& &mut [T]` is like a `T * const *`.

Comment: Another important thing about `impl Trait` in return type position is that it allows you to change the return type without breaking users.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman To a degree -- it breaks ABI, IIRC, but keeps API compatibility.

Comment: Of course, I was talking about API.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman In theory that's true. However, [using impl restricts where consumers can put the returned value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67150842/501250) and so I'm starting to lean towards only using it in a return type where it's absolutely necessary, or in crate-private APIs.